# Limit number of images shown from Jetpack's Tiled Galleries

Tags: wordpress, gallery, jetpack

I have a Tiled Gallery (shortcode) in one of my pages with 20 images. I would like to limit and display only 6 random.

Thanks,
Antonio

Answer (score 0):

After a long time I found a solution combining the Advanced Custom Fields plugin Gallery add on.

Here it is if you ever come across this same issue.

```
<?php
 $images = get_field('gallery-home');
 $image_ids = array();
 $max = 6;
 $i = 0;

  if( $images )
  {
   shuffle($images);

   foreach( $images as $image )
   {
    $i++;
    if( $i > $max){ break; }
    $image_ids[] = $image['id'];
   }
  }

  $shortcode = '[gallery columns="1" link="file" size="medium" ids="' . implode(',', $image_ids) . '"]';
  echo do_shortcode( $shortcode );
?>
```